# How to pass value to another controller view in Xcode

Tags: cocoa

How do i get the value from different UIViewController in xcode storyBoard?

Comment: i have shared my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up using prepareForSegue method.
first i create a string in my third view controller.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* stringFromSecondView;
```

Then I gave the push segue an ID called "getDate" and in my second view class use this code below and remember to import the thirdviewcontroller.h

```
#import "thirdViewController.h"

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"getDate"]){
        NSString *intro = _myDate.text;
        thirdViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.stringFromSecondView = intro;
    }
}
```

Now back to my thirdViewController.m

```
_myLabel.text = stringFromSecondView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second VIew Controller

```
- (IBAction) btnPressToBringThirdView : (id) sender
{
      ThirdViewController* newObject = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
      newObject.labelString = @"whatever text you want";
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:newObject];
      [newObject release];
}
```

In your third viewcontroller in .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* labelString;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     yourLabel.text = labelString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewController *secondview=[[ViewController alloc]init];

secondview.your var here= secondview.your var here+100;//whate you var to change if NSintager
```

///to save your var

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:secondview.your var here forKey:@"your key to save"];
```